# How to project specific elements in an embedded schema in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema:

```
trip : {
source,
destination,
startTime,
endTime
}

and this schema is part of another Schema
tripSchema : {
userId ,
driverId,
trips : [trip]
}
```

Now I specifically want only source and destination from trip Schema in mongoose. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by giving

```
var projection = {
    'trips.startTime' : false,
    'trips.endTime' :false,  
    };
```

and then

```
CollectionName.find({query}, projection, function(err, result){
});
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: but if the item in the projection is an object with say one field inside, how do you get it as a flat variable

Comment: I didn't understand your question.. Could you explain?

Comment: if I say "project":{"price.amount": 1} it gives me price: {amount: "..."} how can I get it back as a flat object instead of a nested one

Comment: You mean to say you want to return the result of a nested object into a flat object. Am I correct? You want a flat object like `amount`  which is equal to price.amount but without using the dot operator you should be able to access it?

Comment: If that is the case if you have an object within an object. I would suggest copying everything into a flat object as I don't know how would Mongo mutate your document and return. Or else, if you want to flatten an array of objects. I would request you to look at [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in MongoDB. But even that would not __exactly__ flatten stuff out.

Comment: yup you are right and no i dont have an array, i would have gone for unwind otherwise, i was assuming something like this would work
project{amount: {"$set": "price.amount"}} but it doesnt

Comment: Why do you need to do that? After you get the document, why can't you flatten it out. The operation you want to try($set)  is in update and not in find.